# Why does user not logged in when using wp_signon function

Tags: wp-redirect

I am registering a new user and after successfully registering I am creating a session for that user and redirecting in to the home page when I register user using the following function

```
wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

It simply registers it and after this function I am calling the following function.

```
wp_signon($user_credentials);
```

And right after that I am redirecting user back to the home page using the following function

```
wp_redirect($url);
```

But these functions are not working for me.
Here's the complete code that I am using right now.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$userdata = array(
    'user_login' => $email,
    'user_pass' => $password,
    'user_email' => $email,
    'user_nicename' => $first_name,
    'display_name' => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name
);

$new_user = wp_insert_user($userdata);

$cred_array = array(
    'user_login' => $email,
    'user_password' => $password,
    'remember' => true
);

$login_user = wp_signon($cred_array);

wp_redirect(get_site_url());

if ( is_wp_error($login_user) ){
    echo $login_user->get_error_message();
}

}

?>
```

Can anyone please help me sorting out this issue it would be great.

Comment: Did you check `$new_user`, if it is inserted  or not ?? You should validate insert and check if `$new_user` is an error.

Comment: Yes sir I have checked it new user is inserted properly.

Comment: I think you are not supposed  to put `wp_redirect` before if statement. It should be below if condition.  Do you get any error?

Comment: No I don't get any errors just the form got reset and user is redirected to same page without authenticated nothing else

Comment: Now I am getting this error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/wp-includes/general-template.php:2663) in /www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 920 `

Answer (score 1):

First of all move the redirect code in case of success. while there is error then no need to redirect the user.

if you are getting the header information warning, then it means error is actually in redirection everything else is working fine. regarding this error, *general-template.php* file is writing down some code in DOM before your redirection. 
Try using meta or jQuery redirection in this case.

Note : sometimes there is only blank space after PHP closing tag **?>** remove the extra spaces at the end from *general-template.php*

Comment: This solution is not working in my case